# How to release memory after pickle.load(file_)

Tags: python, pickle

I have to load multiple pickle files and do some work on them, I am getting a memory error.

Is there a way to release the memory after pickle.load?

My pickle file is gpickle, I have to load it and do some operations on it, once loaded I don't really need the loaded pickle file once the data inside it has been read.

Comment: could you provide some reproducible example code? So we can model the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to `del` the object after it's not needed, rough pseudocode:

```py
data1 = pickle.load(pickle_file1)
# do some work
del data1

data2 = pickle.load(pickle_file2)
# do some work
del data2
```

Comment: I have tried del obj, and gc.collect() but, the output of proc.memory_info().rss is increasing and after certain iterations, I'm getting a memory error.

Comment: Are you running code inside `ipython` or `jupyter`? They tend to have additional references to the objects, which would have to be deleted separately.